# Defining the following relation involving a subset of a poweset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

We have the problem, 
Let $A$ be a non-empty set and let B be a subset of the powerset of A. **Define a relation $R$ from A to B by $xRY $ if $x \in Y$**

I've defined it as follows; $$R={\{(x, Y)\subseteq A\times B |x \in A 
\wedge x\in Y}\}$$

or should I also state Y is a subset of B?

Comment: $(x,Y)$ would be an *element* of $A\times B$, not a subset of it.  In doing and saying so, that implies already that $x\in A$ and $Y\in B$ without needing to say anything extra.  Now, we need to say something related to the condition of what it means for $xRY$ in this case, which would be accomplished by having the condition $x\in Y$.  That is to say, $R=\{(x,Y)\in A\times B\mid x\in Y\}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Helped me a lot thank you!